# Getting object using new operator, copy constructor and clone?

Tags: java

What is the difference in getting new instance(object) using new operator, copy constructor and clone with respect to performance?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it depends. You left off *object pooling* and many *creational* design patterns there. What have you tried and where are you stuck? Because this is a *very* broad question as worded.

Comment: As Java doesn't have copy constructors, 1/3 of your question is moot.

Comment: @EJP you can code one though.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch plus FlyWeight, caching, lazy initialization, and probably ten other patterns

Comment: @Bohemian Of course you can, but as the compiler doesn't (a) generate it or (b) treat it any differently from any other constructor, there is no reason to expect any performance difference; unlike C++ where the compiler might well (a) elide its calling altogether and (b) generate a more efficient copy constructor than you can write.

Comment: A copy constructor is just a special case of "new object".  Clone is simply a way to invoke a copy constructor.  There is no difference to speak of, other than it's usually not that useful to copy other objects vs create new ones with new content.

Comment: Elliott: Yes it broad topic, I will make it very simple, I have used clone in my module. In code review i have got comments like "use copy constructor" instead of clone for better performance. I just want to confirm the same with experts.

Comment: You've been given entirely the wrong reason. There is no reason to expect a hand-written copy constructor to be quicker than cloning. Ask the reviewers for an explanation. If I was reviewing, I would question why you're doing either of them. I've never written either a `clone()` call or a copy constructor in 17 years of Java, other than in experimental code.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Like all code, it depends on how you write it. However, all things being equal, a constructor taking the object you wish to clone as a parameter will be more efficient because you shave off a few function calls (When you implement the clone() method, it's going to have to do everything the constructor does anyways).</del>

<del>That being said, the performance gain is going to be minimal to non-existent.</del>

I stand corrected: EJP points out below that if you don't override it, it actually does a bitwise copy, so it could potentially be faster.

Comment: But when you *don't* implement the `clone()` method there is reason to expect it to be quicker, as it's just a bitwise copy unless a base class has overridden `clone().`

Comment: That's really interesting, I thought that it had to be implemented, but you are indeed correct.